# Integrity of buffers managed by a lock-free container

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, lock-free, memory-barriers

(clarification after two misunderstanding answers: the code works well if the number of producer threads is less than the stack size. There is only 1 consumer releasing slots. The way I tuned this demo with 32 producers VS 16 slots is to trigger a bad condition quickly)

While stress-testing a lock-free stack used for multi-thread buffer management, I discovered that the integrity of buffers' content is not guaranteed. I am quite sure now that the stack/LIFO solution is not the best option; but I still want to understand how are these buffers being compromised.

The idea is: a lock-less stack containing pointers to buffers that are "free". They can be retrieved by one in many producer-threads. Then the buffers are filled with data and "dispatched" to a single consumer thread, which eventually returns them to the stack.

The observation is that either:
- Two threads are somehow getting the same buffer.
- One thread is getting a buffer whose memory is still not flushed from other thread who just released it.

Here is the simplest example I could put together for the purpose of demonstration:

*UPDATE: I made a version with better debug output for anyone who wants to play with it, here: https://ideone.com/v9VAqU*

```
#include <atomic>
#include <assert.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#define N_SLOTS 16
#define N_THREADS 32

// The data buffers that are shared among threads
class Buffer { public: int data[N_THREADS] = {0}; } buffers[N_SLOTS];

// The lock-free stack under study
class LockFreeStack
{
    Buffer* stack[N_SLOTS];
    atomic_int free_slots, out_of_slots, retries;
public:
    LockFreeStack() : free_slots(0), out_of_slots(0), retries(0) {
        for (int i=0; i<N_SLOTS; i++)
            release_buffer(&buffers[i]);
    }
    Buffer* get_buffer()
    {
        int slot = --free_slots;
        if (slot < 0) {
            out_of_slots++;
            return nullptr;
        }
/// [EDIT] CAN GET PREEMPTED RIGHT HERE, BREAKING ATOMICITY!
        return stack[slot];
    }
    void release_buffer(Buffer* buf)
    {
        int slot;
        while(true) {
            slot = free_slots;
            if (slot <= 0) {
                stack[0] = buf;
                free_slots = 1;
                break;
            }
            stack[slot] = buf;
            if (free_slots++ == slot)
                break;
            retries++;
        }
    }
    ostream& toStream(ostream& oss) {
        return oss << "LockFreeStack with free_slots=" << free_slots << ", oos=" << out_of_slots << ", retries=" << retries;
    }
} lockFreeStack;

// Utility class to help with test
class PrintQueue {
    queue<Buffer*> q;
    mutex m;
public:
    void add(Buffer* buf) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        q.push(buf);
    }
    Buffer* pop() {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        Buffer* buf;
        if (q.empty())
            return nullptr;
        buf = q.front();
        q.pop();
        return buf;
    }
} printQueue;

int main()
{
    vector<thread> workers;
    for (int t = 0; t < N_THREADS; ++t) {
        workers.push_back(thread([&,t] {
            while(true) {
                auto buf = lockFreeStack.get_buffer();
                if (buf) {
                    buf->data[t] = t;
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
                    printQueue.add(buf);
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    while(true) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        lockFreeStack.toStream(cout) << endl;
        Buffer *buf;
        while((buf = printQueue.pop())) {
            cout << "Got Buffer " << buf << " #" << (buf-buffers) << " { ";
            int used = 0;
            for(int t=0; t<N_THREADS; t++)
                if (buf->data[t]) {
                    used += 1;
                    cout << 't' << buf->data[t] << ' ';
                    buf->data[t] = 0;
                }
            cout << "}\n";
            assert (used == 1);
            lockFreeStack.release_buffer(buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And a sample of bad output:

```
> LockFreeStack with free_slots=-2454858, oos=2454836, retries=0
> Got Buffer 0x604a40 #12 { t7 }
> Got Buffer 0x6049c0 #11 { t8 }
> Got Buffer 0x604b40 #14 { t1 }
> Got Buffer 0x604bc0 #15 { }
> test.cpp:111: int main(): Assertion `used == 1' failed.
```

I have tried using `std::atomic_thread_fence()` all around the place but it makes no difference.

Where is the fault?

*(btw, tested with several versions of GCC including 5.2 and 4.6)*

Comment: As explained, release_buffer is only used from a *single* consumer thread. And there are no range issues because there are just as many buffers as slots. As long as there are no bad race conditions, which I have not seen in many tests. All I see is that sometimes the buffers themselves, NOT the stack, get corrupted apparently by double access.

Answer (score 2):

Your LockFreeStack code is completely broken.

`release_buffer` called from 2 threads concurrently can stick 2 pointers in the same slot so one is lost.

`if (free_slots++ == slot)` will succeed only for one thread so the other will make another try and put its pointer in another slot. But it could also be the one winning in the first slot so you get the same but in 2 slots.

You can get the same effect with 1 thread calling `release_buffer` and another calling `get_buffer`. And one, or both, these scenarios is responsible for your corruption.

`release_buffer` is not bounded to the size of `stack` so expect buffer overruns and then all hell breaks loose.

I suggest:

1. `release_buffer` first choose a **unique** slot **atomically**, then write to it.
2. When multiple releasers compete for slots, the write order of pointers in slots is not guaranties, so you need some other means to mark a slot as valid on `release_buffer`, and as invalid on `get_buffer`. The easiest way to do it is to null it in `get_buffer`.
3. Bound counters to the size of the stack. If you can not do it one atomic op, take a copy, do all the changes, then cas it back.

**EDIT**

Here's a scenario where the same buffer is returned into 2 cells:

```
                                  ////T==0  free_slots==5

// thread 1
void release_buffer(Buffer* buf)  ////T==1  buf==buffers[7]
{
    int slot;
    while(true) {                 //// 1st iteration
        slot = free_slots;        ////T==2  free_slots==5 slot==5
        if (slot <= 0) {
            stack[0] = buf;            
            free_slots = 1;            
            break;
        }                         ////*** note other threads below ***
        stack[slot] = buf;        ////     stack[5]==buffers[7]
        if (free_slots++ == slot) ////T==5 free_slots==4 slot==5 ---> go for another round
            break;
        retries++;
    }
    while(true) {                 //// 2nd iteration
        slot = free_slots;        ////T==6 free_slots==4 slot==4
        if (slot <= 0) {
            stack[0] = buf;            
            free_slots = 1;            
            break;
        }
        stack[slot] = buf;        ////     stack[4]==buffers[7] //// BOOM!!!!
        if (free_slots++ == slot) ////T==7 free_slots==5 slot==4 ---> no other round
            break;
        retries++;
    }
}

// thread 2
Buffer* get_buffer() // thread
{
    int slot = --free_slots;      ////T==3  free_slots==4
    if (slot < 0) {
        out_of_slots++;
        return nullptr;
    }
    return stack[slot];
}

// thread 3
Buffer* get_buffer()
{
    int slot = --free_slots;      ////T==4  free_slots==3
    if (slot < 0) {
        out_of_slots++;
        return nullptr;
    }
    return stack[slot];
}
```

**EDIT 2: The assertion failure...**

If you haven't found it by now, here it is:

```
//// producer t==0
buf->data[t] = t; //// buf->data[t] == 0

//consumer
for(int t=0; t<N_THREADS; t++)  // first iteration, t==0
  if (buf->data[t]) { //// buf->data[t] == 0, branch not taken
    used += 1;
    ...
  //// used remains ==0   -----> assert fails
```

Writing t+1 in the buffer will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but there is only one thread releasing slots.

Comment: Like I said, even with one releaser, another thread calling get_buffer in the same time can cause a single buffer pointer to get in more than one slot.

Comment: Really? You got all the code to prove it, then. Or you can read the code again and check the ordering between atomic index updates and pointer array access ;-)

Comment: @gatopeich, I don't like your tone one bit. But I will update the answer anyway for others to take something away from it.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to be rude, but "your code is completely broken" was neither polite or correct. No offense here, though! :-) I just want to take the topic to the memory ordering issue. So thanks again for your contribution!

Comment: This is a rather good analysis but there is no "BOOM" really. Okay, we get to `stack[4] == stack[5]`, but `free_slots == 5` so stack[5] is not accessible, it could hold *any* value. Only the successful slot (==4) will ever be retrieved (--free_slots ~ 4). This is the 'trick' of the algorithm here.

Comment: @gatopeich, sorry for the premature "completely broken" it was written with more release threads in mind. Still, there's something I don't completely like about this container. Cannot put the finger on it right now. But the assertion fail is really easy to explain - I'll to the answer:)

Comment: @gatopeich, another issue here: `--free_slots` may eventually flip (with very slow releaser) and you'd get a rough pointer or a segfault. int64 may serve better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas. I eventually found the issue:

1. free_slots == N
2. get_buffer() from consumer thread #2 takes slot N-1, but gets PREEMPTED before reading the pointer in stack[N-1]
3. release_buffer(buf) (single producer thread #1) puts new buffer on the slot that is theorically vacated, precisely stack[N-1]!

Now the pointer originally in stack[N-1] has been lost (memory leak) and the next thread to get_buffer() is going to get the same as thread #2 if it wakes around the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I compiled and executed the following using gcc 5.3 on Linux:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        std::atomic_int n;

        std::cout << n << std::endl;

        n=4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output was as follows:

```
306406976
4
4
4
4
```

From that, I concluded that `std::atomic_int`'s constructor does not explicitly clear the initial value of the atomic integer. It must be explicitly initialized. I wanted to verify this fact because I am not very familiar with the atomic library. My results suggest that `std::atomic_int`s must be explicitly initialized, they won't get automatically initialized to 0s.

I was prompted to verify whether or not `std::atomic_int`s were being initialized, or not, based on the following observations:

- Here, the `LockFreeStack` constructor does not explicitly initialize the `std::atomic_int` class members either.
- The constructor invokes the `release_buffer()` method.
- The `release_buffer`() method reads and uses `free_slots`.

From this, I must conclude that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: clang++-3.6 on Linux initializes the atomic_int to 4. I refuse to believe that is standard-conforming, but I will look it up.

Comment: I'm confident that it doesn't initialize it to anything. The code in question simply reuses the same address on the stack, for each iteration of the loop, so you're simply looking at the previous instance's value. Which also happens in my case, except that on the first iteration the stack contains some random garbage.

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, there isn't a previous user-supplied value on the stack during the first cout statement. If clang reordered the atomic load/store instructions around the cout, then it did not uphold the sequentially consistent behavior that is supposed to be the default.

29.6.5.4 guarantees that a default-constructed std::atomic<T> is left uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks, but I had explicit (0) and {0} initializers before and made no difference. Besides, such behaviour would crash the test code immediately because they are indexing a small array.

Comment: No hard feelings but this is a bad answer, since *static* data is zero-initialized by default: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: @gatopeich You mean the default constructor of your members is called (no static anywhere in sight after all) and what does that one do? "Leaves the atomic object in an uninitialized state". Probably not the reason for any problems, but a bug nevertheless

Comment: @Voo, the relevant instances are declared in main's global space, aka 'static'. I changed to a more explicit form for clarity but these comments really are off topic here.